# How to run schedular at background along with rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thin, rufus-scheduler

I am using Rufus Scheduler to send  mail alerts daily at specific time. I have created task_scheduler.rb inside config/initializers.my code is :-

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

 scheduler.cron("0 09 * * *") do
   UserMailer.leave_reminder_email().deliver
 end
end
```

it works fine when i run "rails s" command. but when i use, "rails server thin -d", it do not work. can anyone please tell me what else is required to make it work? thnks

Comment: "it doesn't work" does not help.

Please read: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this on top of the task_scheduler.rb:

```
require 'rufus/scheduler'
```